# Write pandas DataFrame to CSV file. The result gets extra rows

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I have a CSV file. After doing some changes on columns, I want to export it as a new CSV file. Here is my code:

```
gpa_full = pd.read_csv("gpo_full.csv")
gpa_full["held_date"] = gpa_full["held_date"].str.replace("\r", "")
gpa_full["held_date"] = gpa_full["held_date"].str.replace("\t", "")
```

Everything shows good in pandas DataFrame, but after converting it to csv file,

```
gpa_full.to_csv("gpa_full.csv", encoding='utf-8')
```

I get many extra rows like this:
[image]

```
line1  line2  members   link   title   url 
1.     1.     Bob, Sharon, Susan, Helen
//www.govinfo.gov/content/pkg/CHRG-106shrg74729/html/CHRG-106shrg74729.htm, Protecting Privacy, url
```

The link is in the next row. More specifically, the content of the columns after members is all in the next row.

I tried to read csv file to find problems

```
pd.read_csv("gpa_full.csv")
```

I get error and it shows: 
ParserError: Error tokenizing data. C error: Buffer overflow caught - possible malformed input file. 
How can I fix this? Thanks!!!

Comment: What if you print the `df` , Does it comes all good in shape?

Comment: Yes, all good in shape

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First try to export as Excel format:

```
gpa_full.to_excel("gpa_full.xlsx", encoding='utf-8')
```

If you want a csv file, try to change the separator `sep`:

```
gpa_full.to_csv("gpa_full.csv", sep='\t', encoding='utf-8')
```

Comment: Excel format works, but csv file does not.

Comment: Try to add `quoting= csv.QUOTE_NONNUMERIC` (you need to `import csv`). Obviously, when you `read_csv` don't forget to set the same parameters.